# multiple hosts and multiple metric_path in prometheus using files

Tags: prometheus

i have 100's of servers and every server has 10's of metric_path. i am able to scrape all hosts but its automatically adding /metric after every host.

```
`global:
  scrape_interval: 30s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'file_sd_targets'  
    metrics_path: '/configuration/1'
    
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - /etc/prometheus/targets.json
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '([^:]+):.*'
        target_label: instance
        replacement: '$1'`
```

what i have in target.json is

`[ { "target": "1.2.3.4:10091", "metrics_paths": ["/configuration/1", "/analytics/1"] }, { "target": "1.2.3.5:10091", "metrics_paths": ["/configuration/1", "/analytics/1"] }, { "target": "1.2.3.6:10091", "metrics_paths": ["/configuration/1", "/analytics/1"] } ]`

but i am seeing this in the UI
http://1.2.3.4:100091/metric

expected output:
http://1.2.3.4:100091/configuration/1
http://1.2.3.4:100091/analytics/1
http://1.2.3.5:100091/configuration/1
http://1.2.3.5:100091/analytics/1
http://1.2.3.6:100091/configuration/1
http://1.2.3.6:100091/analytics/1

Comment: Hello, sorry - I can't follow your question. Can you describe your problem and what you expect instead a bit clearer? For example with an example of what is wrong and how it should look like?

Comment: As far as I see it in the documentation, file_sd_configs does not allow for "metrics_paths" and only target and labels. You could try creating multiple jobs for each type of metrics_path, and, if you need them under a unified name, relabel the job afterwards to file_sd_targerts again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`metrics_path` can be set only on the job level: see the description of configuration file format [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config). I believe this is due to the fact that metrics path is not stored into labels by default, and thus allowing you do scrape same host on different paths within one job would create possibility of conflicts.

[`file_sd_config` only allows for targets and labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config).

Most straightforward approach for your situation is to create a job per `metrics_path`.

---

A couple alternatives:

1. If you are not interested in the path from which metric was scraped, you can create a (self-developed) simple aggregating service, that will respond with metrics from all the services of current host.
2. I think you can utilize [`<relabel_config>`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) and set `__metrics_path__` through it. (I haven't tested this approach, I do believe this should work.) Config will look something like this:

```
      - targets: ["host1:9091", "host2:9091"]
        labels:
          path: path1
      - targets: ["host2:9091", "host3:9091"]
        labels:
          path: path2
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
```